# find the the variable that maximizes a function

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I have a function that I am trying to find for what input it maximizes.

$$ f(n) = {\binom{S}{2}}^{n/S}$$

I need to find the $S$ for which this function maximizes (for infinite $n$).
more generally, I need to find the correct $S$ for each given $m$. (in this case $m=2$)

$$ f(n) = {\binom{S}{m}}^{n/S}$$

I think that for the first equation the result is $S=5$ but I am not sure..

How do I approach the second problem? how can I find the maximum based on 2 variables?

**EDIT**
n,S and m are integers.

Comment: For the first equation, how did you arrive to $S=5$, which is the correct answer ?

Comment: Hint: $n$ is irrelevant. Also maximum seems to be when $S=2m+1$.

Comment: @user844541: You probably mean "for all $n$", rather than "for infinite $n$", right?

Comment: @ManolitoPérez I meant that I want to get the $S$ that maximizes the value when $n$ gets bigger and bigger. i.e. if for a small $n$ some value of $s$ gets you an higher result, but for very large $n$ a different $s$ will give you the higher result, I want the second $s$. is that clear?

Comment: @Macavity how did you get to this result?